# How to handle, if .class contain password?

Tags: java, security

I am having some .java file those contain some password variables, and these variables have password value.

String password = "xyz";

Now after run, when i open .class file, it contain those passwords. How to handle this case. I don't want to use DB for storing. And if i'll change the variable name then also it'll contain password.

**I want .class should not contain any password value.

Comment: why it's a java file, can't it be a data/properties file ?

Comment: it shouldn't be in the java class, it should be in an external properties file or similar. this is so you can easy change the value without having to compile the code, and the value wont be in the source code. this is true for all sorts of properties. but even this file can be easily read. its a common problem though securing the passwords on a server. i assume the code is going to go on a server. your application will probably have a context file which contains the username and password for the database. so the same issue is there, ensuring no one can easily access that.

Comment: @Mritunjay It can be anything. I was using java file so i mentioned.

Comment: security.stackexchange.com might be a better forum for Java keystore questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not advisable to store the password directly, instead use some kind of Encryption techniques to store the encrypted values.
As long as you are using the Encryption seed, you can decrypt it easily using the same seed.

Comment: If i'll use any encryption technique then also i need the value to encrypt. like in this example it's using password:-                                                                                  public class EncryptExample {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  String password = "secret";
  String algorithm = "SHA";
  byte[] plainText = password.getBytes();
  MessageDigest md = null;
  md = MessageDigest.getInstance(algorithm);
  md.reset();  
  md.update(plainText);
  byte[] encodedPassword = md.digest();
 }
}  How to do this?

Comment: No, you don't.  Write one program to encrypt it, then hardcode the encrypted value into another program.

Answer (score 0):

You have to encode your password and set the encoded password to that variable. using

```
String encodePassword(String rawPass, Object salt) throws DataAccessException
```

When you need to check that the given password by user is valid or not, use

```
boolean isPasswordValid(String encPass, String rawPass, Object salt) throws DataAccessException
```

see [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/encoding/PasswordEncoder.html)

Answer (score -2):

One way is not to save password, but encrypt it and save the encrypted text. That way, when you need to verify the password, you can simply encrypt the incoming text using same logic and compare. If you still need the password, then you can decrypt back and use.

Comment: Don't roll your own keystore.